# Does Graph API support POSTing a Bot app feature to Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am trying to use Graph API to automate the process of creating a Microsoft Teams app with a Bot app feature.

I found this Graph API endpoint called [publish teamsapp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsapp-publish?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) which allows me to POST a Teams app package and instantiate a Teams app. Below, the "Appr 4 - MS Teams Test" app was created by uploading an app package to the aforementioned endpoint.

[App published through Graph API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylv2r.png)

However, in order to complete this automation, I need to create a Bot app feature under "Configure > App features" of my Teams app.

My problem is that the publish teamsapp doesn't seem to support creating the Bot app feature. The app package' that you upload contains a `manifest.json`. The [schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema) of this manifest only allows you to provide a Bot ID (presumably for an existing bot). You cannot specify the webhook URL for this bot and there do not appear to be any APIs to generate the bot's client secret.

[App features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvlPT.png)

My question is, are there any Microsoft APIs that would allow me to create, read from, and write to bot app features? Ideally, I would like to be able to do the following:

1. Create the bot app feature
2. Retrieve the bot ID associated with the bot
3. Set the webhook URL of the bot
4. Create a client secret associated with the bot
5. Retrieve the client secret so I can store in my own database.

Answer (score 0):

Is this step 1 to step a loop you would like to follow? I will consider Azure Logic APP to do the bot API call to create a bot - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-first-logic-app-workflow

Also, there is a forum actively monitoring by Teams-dev member you may want to check there as well - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/topics/single/58062.html